# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в файл: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u039a'

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8, unicode

Требуется пропарсить `vk` по заданым параметрам и записать результат в файл на Python 3.5.

```
search_result = api.users.search(sort=sort_index, sex=sex_index, age_to=age_index, offset=offset_index, count=count_index, country=country)

result = open('result.txt','a')
while index != (count_index - offset_index):
    result.write(str(search_result[index + 1]))
    result.write('\n')
    index += 1
result.close()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:***\vkscript.py", line 19, in <module>
    result.write(str(search_result[index + 1]))
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u039a' in position 16: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Надо попробовать указать кодировку файла `result = open('result.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Я делаю в виндовс 10 не помогает, как быть?

Comment: @Алекс задавать свой вопрос с воспроизводимым примером кода и конкретным описанием того, что именно значит "не помогает".

Answer (score 9):

Добавьте параметр `encoding`. Просто, по умолчанию там взялась кодировка `cp1251`:

```
open('result.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

И чтобы не пришлось вручную вызывать `close`, используйте менеджер контекста, он сам закроет:

```
with open('result.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while index != (count_index - offset_index):
        f.write(str(search_result[index + 1]))
        f.write('\n')
        index += 1
```

Comment: весь цикл вероятно можно заменить на `print(*search_result, sep='\n', file=f)`. Если только часть результатов хочется сохранить, то можно `search_result[index+1:count_index - offset_index + 1]` вместо `search_result` печатать.

Comment: хорошо выглядит у вас )

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло:

```
with open('books.csv', 'wt', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    fout.write(books)
```