# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 178: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

```
filename = 'users_data.txt'

file = open(filename,'r')
users = []
users = json.load(file)
file.close()
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>   File "D:\Mahmud\Python\mybot.py", line 28, in <module>     
>     users = json.load(file)   
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load     
>     return loads(fp.read(),   
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Py
> ```

Помогите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю почему вылетает эта ошибка и что делать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с кодировкой при записи в файл: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u039a'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509576/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-can)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не парсится JSON через Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980205/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-json-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-python)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте io.open(), при использовании codecs могут быть проблемы с режимом универсальных строк:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as file:
    for line in file:
        process(line)
```

или попробуйте просто:

```
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```